# Typescript React: How to get type which depends on prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some own props of component which contains element type:

```
export interface LinkProps {
  ...
  Element: 'a' | 'button' | 'span';
  ...
}
```

How i can get type of own props and props of this HTML element?

This way works, but it's overhead and I want to understand how don't use hardcode

```
export interface LinkProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement | HTMLButtonElement | HTMLSpanElement> { ... }
```

Also we can use `JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]`, but how include it into interface or type of props?

Component starts from

```
export class Link extends React.PureComponent<LinkProps> {
  ...
}
```